# Liquor bottle puzzle in Eavesdropper comic strip

Tags: liquor, identification

[Strip 10 of the Eavesdropper comic strip](http://www.mezzacotta.net/eavesdropper/episodes/0010.html) shows a small bar with a sequence of seven liquor bottles on a shelf.  Can you identify them?

[image]

The comic strip apparently has a series of puzzles, with one puzzle encoding a word found on each page of the comic strip (except for the first few pages).  We don't yet know where the puzzles are going, but then the comic only has 18 pages so far out of approximately 100 planned.

We have already identified a few of those bottles, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already have three bottles identified.  From left to right

- First bottle may be **[Gekkeikan Junmai Skye Blue Sake](https://www.glengarrywines.co.nz/items/90979/gekkeikan+junmai+skye+blue+sake+%28720ml%29)**, [suggested by crypdex](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=166272#166272)
- Second bottle may be **[Bols Advocaat](https://www.dutyfree.ca/products/spirits/liqueur/advocaat)**, [suggested by OldPadawan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptSXk.png)
- Third bottle is **[Midori](https://www.danmurphys.com.au/product/DM_91199/midori-melon-liqueur-700ml.jsp)**, [identified by kazzie](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=166256#166256).
- Fourth bottle is **[Benedictine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9n%C3%A9dictine)**, [identified by Yendor](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=166298#166298)
- Fifth bottle is **[Choya Umeshu plum wine](http://www.totalwine.com/wine/sake-plum-wine/plum-wine/choya-umeshu-with-plum/p/96718750?s=1108&igrules=true)**, [identified by ellison](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/a/7039/7187) in his answer
- Sixth bottle is **[Cointreau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointreau)**, [identified by kazzie](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/draakslair/viewtopic.php?p=166256#166256)
- Seventh bottle is **[Antitoxin Absinthe](https://www.absinthes.com/en/absinthe-antitoxin-p899)** in skull bottle, identified by me.

[image: Sake][image: Advocaat][image: Midori][image: Benedictine][image: Umeshu][image: Cointreau][image: Antitoxin]

The solution might be another liquor, [**Sambuca**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sambuca), from reading together the first letters of "Skye, Advocaat, Midori, Benedictine, Umeshu, Cointreau, Antitoxin".

[image: Sambuca]

Comment: could 2nd bottle be [BOLS advocaat](https://goo.gl/images/iP84bV)?

Answer (score 3):

5th bottle is [Choya plum wine](http://www.totalwine.com/media/sys_master/twmmedia/h28/h94/9665359118366.png).